# How to open different local files according to the result?

Tags: javascript

I'm very new to javascript and I'm having an issue with this script:

```
function processInp() {
    var x = parseInt(document.querySelector('input[name="num"]').value);
    if (!x) {
        alert("NaN");
        return false
    } else if (x > 480) {
        alert("Overflow!");
        return false
    }
    window.open("../files/" + x + '.html');
    return true
}
```

First, it checks if the input is a number, then if it is higher than 480, so throw an alert and an error. That's completly fine and working. What I really can't do is opening the url according to the input. Is it possible with numbers? How? Full example if possible. Thank you!

Comment: yes, javascript will convert x to a strong for you in this case, so your `window.open` line should return `"../files/12.html"`?

Comment: @Stu yes, if 12 is the user input, yes.

Comment: ah ok, I thought that was the intention? How do you want to open files depending on the user input? i.e. a different value depending on a range of inputs etc?

Comment: If input is 1, open 1.html. If it is 450, open 450.html. @Stu

Comment: that should work in your case then? ix x = 12, it'll open "../files/12.html"? if x = 110 it'll open "../files/110.html"

Comment: yes @Stu, that's what it should do.

Comment: this is what your code outputs, sorry if I'm not seeing the question right: https://jsfiddle.net/8qd5t1x8/

Comment: @Stu no, and there's nothing special with the number 12, also. It does nothing, just updates the url adding ?num=[input] (for example ?num=1

Comment: ah ok, so what do you want to happen when the number x validates (i.e. is a number and is lower than 480?) What do you want to do with "15.html" (in a case where x = 15)

Comment: @MucaP then that code isn't running. What you are seeing is the default behaviour when submitting a form. If your code had run, then it would have opened a different page.

Comment: @Stu No, that's nothing to do with ranges. If input is 1, *open* 1.html in a new page. If it is 2, open 2.html and it goes like that, there's a page for all the inputs.

Comment: @Vld Yes, but I can't see why it is not running

Comment: then @Vld is right, you need to bind this behavior to the form when you want the behavior to happen

Comment: ok cool, so the question is; "how do I get the below code to run when someone submits a form"? or "how do I get the below code to run when someone updates an input text box?"?

Comment: @Stu yes, look at that fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9e91gmso/

Comment: @MucaP, thanks, adding the form into the example gives it context and a lot easier to try to help :)

Comment: @Stu You're welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your example https://jsfiddle.net/9e91gmso/, I think this might be due to scope.

As changing the line `function processInp() {` to `window.processInp = function () {` (i.e. https://jsfiddle.net/9e91gmso/1/) seems to work correctly?

I think this is a pretty good post about scope if you want to read up further: [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Comment: That problem might be specific to JSFiddle. The function should have been hoisted to the top, assuming it was in the global scope to begin with.

Comment: @Vld, exactly, I don't propose this is the absolute answer, but I think looking at the scope and positioning of code in the actual app would help point to the right solution :)

Comment: why the -1? I'm trying to point OP in the right direction, and I think I've explained why and how...

Comment: @Stu oh, yes - it helps to be explicit in assigning the function to the `window` object - that way, even if it's wrapped in a closure later on for whatever reason, it would still work. Just wanted to point out that the behaviour in JSFiddle is not necessarily "representative" of how it works. EDIT: also, didn't downvote.

Comment: @Vld 100% agree, but as we can't see OP's full code I can only speculate as to the right answer, having said that I'm pretty sure it's a scope issue, i.e. the form can't see the function in the jsfiddle... but agree it needs to be looked in further, hence the scope link that I thought might help :)